# Extracting unrecognized information from many CSV files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, glob

I am new to programming and I have a many CSV files that need to be processed. Each CSV file has an 8 line header. After the header, there are rows of names and data. The second column has a bunch of names for products which is what I am primarily concerned with right now. Each product has a certain set of names that is recognized by our computers. For example shoe would be recognized as: shoe, sneaker, heel, loafer, etc. Over time, other names have sneaked into the CSV files that the computers cannot recognize. I want to get these names from the CSV files and populate a text file that I can go through, sort, and add to the computers. There is also so extra information at the bottom of the CSVs that is separated from this information by an empty line.

I know that I should probably use the glob module as well as numpy and or pandas but I just don't know how to incorporate everything I need into any sort of working program. Here is my initial attempt at a code.

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

fns = glob.glob('*.csv') 

for fn in fns:
    data = np.genfromtxt(fns, delimiter=',')

    if 'Shoe' or 'Heel' or 'Loafer' or 'sneaker':

    elif 'shirt' or 'tee' or 'tank' or 'polo':

    else:
```

If anyone has any bits of code that could help it would be nice, but any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

The CSVs look something like this

```
Name    bunch of stuff                          
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
Count   5                           
NUMBER  ITEM    MORE    PRICE1  PRICE2  ETA GOOD    FAULTY  OTHER
N1  Shoe    stuff                                           
N2  Heel    stuff                                           
N3  Tee                                   I     K   
N4  Polo    other   stuff               G       J   
N5  Sneaker other   stuff               H       N
```

Comment: Could you post a few defining lines of your csv file? An example of desired output would be great too if possible.

Comment: [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is a really useful library for dealing with csv files. Depending on the specifics of your problem, it might simplify things.

Comment: @sihrc I hope my edit helps. As for output, a list of unidentified things is what im looking for. It just needs to be semi readable when I look through it

Answer (score 2):

Your data format was a little hard to make sense of (is the actual data tab-separated?) so I've turned it into a somewhat simpler example:

```
Name    bunch of stuff                          
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
header stuff    stuff                           
Count   5                           
NUMBER,ITEM
N1,Shoe
N2,Heel
N3,Tee
N4,Polo
N5,Sneaker
```

You can read in a csv file like this using pandas, skipping the header with `skiprows`:

```
import pandas as pd
prod_df = pd.read_csv('prod.csv', skiprows=7)
```

Then you can find which values are in your data (note that the `unique()` call means you'll only get each value once, even if there are hundreds of duplicates of each):

```
data_products = prod_df['ITEM'].unique()
data_products
Out[22]: array(['Shoe', 'Heel', 'Tee', 'Polo', 'Sneaker'], dtype=object)
```

And compare them to the values they should have:

```
valid_products = ['Shoe', 'Sneaker']
invalid_data = [x for x in data_products if x not in valid_products]
invalid_data
Out[25]: ['Heel', 'Tee', 'Polo']
```

Comment: Is there any way that i can adapt this to read through hundreds of CSVs by using something like `glob`

Comment: You should use a loop by using something like `for`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are being lazy enough. Making the computer do all the work is what makes programming fun. I would load the names the computer can recognize into a set. Then read through the CSV. Its a pretty straightforward problem so I probably wouldn't complicate it with Pandas or numpy.  Make a dict for unrecognized terms. When you get to an unrecognized term, add it to the dict using the term as the key and an array of the known terms associated with that same item as the value.

When you are done reading through the CSV, iterate through the unrecognized terms and use the associated known terms to predict what the term means.

Comment: `pandas` is *very* good at dealing with CSV formatted data, so using it isn't necessarily 'complicating' the solution. `numpy` is probably a bit too low-level though.

Comment: Now that you posted data, it doesn't look like you'll be able to do the association bit. Unless "stuff" has more meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely a fan of solutions using Pandas, but here is a solution using the `csv` module (using made up data).

```
#Data for example
f = StringIO("""Number,Item,Price
0,a,.50
1,A,.50
2,B,.75
3,B,.75""")

#Read Data using csv module
parser = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')      #may have to change delimiter

for row in parser:
    print "row data:", "\t", row
    if row['Item'].upper() == 'A': print 'Row contains Item A'
    else: print 'Row does not have Item A'
    print
```

which produces:

```
row data:       {'Item': 'a', 'Price': '.50', 'Number': '0'}
Row contains Item A

row data:       {'Item': 'A', 'Price': '.50', 'Number': '1'}
Row contains Item A

row data:       {'Item': 'B', 'Price': '.75', 'Number': '2'}
Row does not have Item A

row data:       {'Item': 'B', 'Price': '.75', 'Number': '3'}
Row does not have Item A
```

The biggest thing to take away is looping through `DictReader` will produce a dictionary for each row of your CSV file. Depending on what separates each entry of your csv file, you might have to change the delimiter, which tells python how to tell the entries apart.